# Why does now.tobinary give two different results?

Tags: vb.net

Below is a copy and paste from my immediate window in VS2010. Notice that the string representations of the Now function are the same, but their binary representations are vastly different. Unwrapping the Now function from CDate makes no difference. Why?

```
?CDate(Now)

1/8/2013 10:06:46 AM

?CDate(Now.ToString)

1/8/2013 10:06:52 AM

?CDate(Now.ToString).ToBinary

634932364230000000

?CDate(Now).ToBinary

-8588439384563815032

?Now.ToBinary

-8588439380551725996
```

Notice that I am now working with the exact same time on every line. Why do I get the "abberant" numerical result when I use the ToString function?

```
?Now.ToBinary

-8588439366264255565

?datetime.FromBinary(-8588439366264255565)

1/8/2013 10:37:39 AM

?datetime.FromBinary(-8588439366264255565).ToBinary

-8588439366264255565

?cdate(datetime.FromBinary(-8588439366264255565).ToString ).ToBinary 

634932382590000000

?CDate(datetime.FromBinary(-8588439366264255565)).ToBinary

-8588439366264255565
```

Comment: Because Now changes (string representation as well)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I understand the small changes, it is the big difference (positive/negative) from the first number to the last two that I am wondering about.

Comment: A millisecond change in date/time can result in a huge difference in binary value. There's no straight correlation between original value and binary result (e.g. +1 in one result will not result in +1 in another) similarly to GetHashCode algorithms. If you need this sort of behavior - you will have to implement your own function/extention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because DateTime.Now has millisecond precision, but when you call ToString, milliseconds are not printed. The two dates are not the same anymore.

If you print the date with a format which includes milliseconds, you will get the same result:

```
Dim testDate = DateTime.Now()
Console.WriteLine(testDate.ToBinary)
Dim testDateToString = CDate(testDate.ToString("O"))
Console.WriteLine(testDateToString.ToBinary)
```

Output:

```
-8588439319484221453
-8588439319484221453
```

Answer (score 1):

`Now' keeps current date/time which constantly changes. If you want value to remain the same - assign it to a variable first and then use the variable in the rest of the code.

EDIT

If you want to see small millisecond-like changes try using something like `Now.ToFileTime`